# Proper use of for loops in Matlab

Tags: matlab

```
for ii=1:size(K) 
  Xsol(ii) =  (K(ii) - average/2) ; 
  Xsag(ii) =  (K(ii) + average/2) ;
end
```

I get the following output:

```
Xsol =

    5.5000

Xsag =

   36.5000
```

But  it could be like that `Xsol(1)` and `Xsol(2)`. How could I get this?

Answer (score 4):

If `K` is a 1 x N matrix, then `size(K)` yields `[1 N]`. When you use it your `for` loop, it does not work because it is not a scalar (actually, and quite painfully, Matlab simply uses the first element to limit the loop, and does not even issue a warning). Instead, write:

```
for ii=1:numel(K) 
  Xsol(ii) =  (K(ii) - average/2) ; 
  Xsag(ii) =  (K(ii) + average/2) ;
end
```

The function `numel` returns a scalar, i.e.,  the total number of elements.

However, as pointed out by @Jonas, you do not need a loop in this case. In general, loops are extremely slow as compared to array operations.

Comment: This is the solution to the problem (though the loop is unnecessary). +1.

Comment: @Jonas: yes indeed, the loop is unnecessary :P

Answer (score 2):

Instead of performing the calculation inside a loop, you can also call

```
Xsol = K - average/2;
Xsag = K + average/2;
```